# Inserting '€' symbol in SQL Server and getting an '?'

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server-2008, encoding

I have a DLL Library in C++ which inserts some data. There is a nvarchar field in which I insert data from the user.

I tried converting the string from `Latin1` (`ISO-8859-1`) to `UTF-8` before inserting in order to have other symbols correctly inserted: accents and other special symbols (á, ñ, ó, etc.). But no luck (well, the other symbols are correctly inserted, but not the euro sign). It keeps inserting an `?` instead of every `€` no matter what I do.

My column has `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` encoding.

**Example:**

Inserting string:

```
something € something
```

Results in this in database:

```
something ? something
```

---

**EDIT:**

The string comes from a desktop .NET application that passes the string to the C++ dll. The string is captured with a normal .NET TextBox and is stored on a normal String.

The string is converted in the C++/CLI wrapper with this:

```
static std::string strConvert(String ^source) {
    return marshal_as<std::string>(source);
}
```

And then the std::string is inserted into database through `ODBC`.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 doesn't contain €, which is U+20A0. So I don't know what string you had, but if it was ever in ISO-8859-1, it didn't include the Euro symbol.

Comment: try using COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Comment: @JonSkeet Then which encoding has the original string? UNICODE? (the string comes from .NET desktop application)

Comment: @SysDragon: ISO-8859-15 has it, as well as Microsoft's CP1252. (But switching to Unicode sounds like a good idea.)

Comment: Well how are you getting the string *from* the .NET application? You really haven't provided us enough context to know what's going on.

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert by any means, but I've have thought you'd need a `wstring` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to avoid the encoding and let the SQL Server handle this particular character manually.

Simply replacing every `€` symbol in the string to `' + CHAR(128) + '` before inserting it.

```
parValue = replace(parValue, "€", "' + CHAR(128) + '");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a column with a character set that supports the Euro character.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    MyEuroColumn VARCHAR(5)
      CHARACTER SET utf8
      COLLATE utf8_general_ci 
);
```

If your editor doesn't support Unicde, you can insert it like this:

```
select concat('Five ', _ucs2 0x20AC, ' please!')
```

You can also store the Euro symbol in [other](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) character sets:

```
UTF-8                  0xE282AC
UCS-16                 0x20AC
ISO-8859-15 (latin-9)  0xA4
```

Comment: the `_ucs2 0x20AC` is not recognized and gives error. Maybe is MySQL only?

Comment: Yes, this solution works on MySQL. MIGHT work on other, but only on MySQL is for sure.

Comment: neh, everything in this answer is MySQL only (syntax, functions, etc). But thanks for the advice. As you can see in the question I work with SQL Server

Comment: SQL Server [doesn't even work with UTF8 encoding](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/sql-server-2005-2008-utf-8-collation-charset)

Comment: It was a sugestion, I saw that you use SQL S, but didn't know if it's fixed or the closest solution would do it :).